# Imprimir datos que necesito y no necesito en una consulta

Tags: sql

¿Que puedo usar para tratar el siguiente requerimiento?:

Muestre los los productos comprados y no comprados de la orden 10256, el mensaje de los no comprados debe ser "No comprado".

La consulta convencional solo me traería los datos comprados pero como hago para mostrar los no comprados? tengo esta linea de consulta hasta el momento

```
select ProductName, OrderDetails.OrderID 
from Products inner join OrderDetails
on OrderDetails.ProductID=Products.ProductID where 
OrderDetails.OrderID='10256'
```

Gracias anticipadas!

Comment: ¿Como se determina que un producto haya sido comprado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que seria algo así, con un `left join`.

```
select P.ProductName, D.OrderID, Case When D.OrderID Is Null Then 'No Comprado' Else 'Comprado' End Estado 
from Products P
left join OrderDetails D on D.ProductID=P.ProductID 
where D.OrderID='10256'
```

Si el producto no tiene registro en la tabla `OrderDetail` significa que no ha sido comprado, y si no tiene registro el `left join` te devolvería un null y si es null entonces devolvemos el texto No Comprado, de lo contrario ha sido Comprado

Comment: capo, muchas gracias!!!